# NullPointerException in Java/MySQL application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm building a Movie Rating CRUD application and whenever I click on the 'Categories' link, which is supposed to access the database and display the categories and the list of movies available, I receive an error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Database.ConnectionPool.freeConnection(ConnectionPool.java:40)
Database.ItemDB.getItems(ItemDB.java:59)
Controllers.CatalogController.processRequest(CatalogController.java:33)
Controllers.CatalogController.doGet(CatalogController.java:86)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

### ItemDB.java

```
public static ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
    
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Item";
            
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        while(rs.next()) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setItemCode(rs.getString("itemCode"));
            item.setItemName(rs.getString("itemName"));
            item.setCatalogCategory(rs.getString("CatalogCategory"));
            item.setItemDescription(rs.getString("descript"));
            item.setItemRating(rs.getString("itemRating"));
            item.setImageUrl(rs.getString("imageURL"));
            items.add(item);
        }
        return items;
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

### ConnectionPool.java

```
public void freeConnection(Connection c) {
    try {
        c.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

### Context.xml

```
<Resource 
          auth="Container" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          logAbandoned="true" 
          maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
          name="jdbc/MovieThoughts"  removeAbandoned="true" 
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/root" 
          username="MovieThoughts" password=[my_password] />
```

I've tested the connection in my MySQL workbench and it can establish the connection in there.

Comment: You should be using try-with-resources anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at it, I'd say `pool.getConnection()` returns `null` and that causes an NPE at `connection.prepareStatement(query)`, which is swallowed when the `finally` block throws its own NPE.

In general, you should try to write your `finally` blocks so that they can't throw exceptions, both because of the swallowing above and because if an exception occurs part of the `finally` code might be skipped.

eg. in your code if `DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs)` throws (which might very well be impossible, depending on how `DBUtil` is implemented), the following two statements will be skipped, possibly resulting in leaking a connection.

Since Java 7 (IIRC), the preferred way to deal with all this is the try-with-resource construct (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which basically deals with the boilerplate for you.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell usually i got that erreur if i wrongly type password

did you try another way than using the connection pool by using the dataSource directly. Maybe something wrongly configure with the connection pool.

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context ctx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/MovieThoughts");

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try disable maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"